# Gridview ObjectDataSource fill through stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, objectdatasource

I have this `ObjectDataSource`

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource 
     ID="oDataSourceHistoricoDoencasCliente" runat="server" 
     DeleteMethod="DeleteById" 
     InsertMethod="Insert" 
     SelectMethod="SelectByIdCliente" 
     TypeName="SOSSemTempo.BusinessObjects.Pessoa.HistoricoDoencasCliente">
     <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
     </DeleteParameters>
     <InsertParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="IdCliente" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="IdDoenca" Type="Int32" />
     </InsertParameters>
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="IdCliente" QueryStringField="Id" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="NULL" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="IdDoenca" Type="Int32" />
     </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I am trying to use the `SelectMethod` `SelectByIdCliente` to receive data from a stored procedure. But when the page loads, the method is called (I used a breakpoint to check) and the method returns a `DataReader` with the expected rows, but after executing the method the grid displays empty.

This is the `SelectByIdCliente` method:

```
public SqlDataReader SelectByIdCliente(int IdCliente)
{
        return Database.ExecuteStoredProcedureDataReader("sprSelectHistoricoDoencaCliente", new string[] { "IdCliente" }, new object[] { IdCliente });
}

public static SqlDataReader ExecuteStoredProcedureDataReader(string strStoredProcedureName, string[] strParameters, object[] oValues)
{
    return GetSqlCommand(strStoredProcedureName, strParameters, oValues).ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}

private static SqlCommand GetSqlCommand(string strStoredProcedureName, string[] strParameters, object[] oValues)
{
        if (strParameters.Length != oValues.Length)
            throw new Exception("Numero de parametros e valores não batem.");

        SqlConnection conn = Database.GetConnection();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strStoredProcedureName, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int i = 0; i < strParameters.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(strParameters[i], oValues[i]);
        }

        return cmd;
    }
```

Does anyone knows what am I missing?

UPDATE: `GridView` that is using the `ObjectDataSource`

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="gvHistoricoDoencaCliente" 
    runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="true"
    DataSourceID="oDataSourceHistoricoDoencasCliente" 
    EmptyDataText="Não há registros de histórico de doença para este cliente." 
    ShowFooter="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake. I was using `Paging` and `Sorting` on the `Grid View`, both not supported when using `ObjectDataSource` without manual implementation. I noticed after trying other aproaches like using a `<asp:Button>` to get `DataSource` and using `DataBind()`. That threw an `exception` that the application wasn't throwing before. I will update my question with the GridView code for better visualization.